# string.format() with coustom hex-format

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

I need to format an integer as a MAC-Address (01-1A-1B-2B-30 and so on). Is there a way to to this directly with string.format()?
All my attepts so far have failed:

```
string.Format("{0:X}", 1234567); //Output: 12D687 It is hex, but not formatted
string.Format("{0:00-00-00-00}", 1234567); //Output: 01-23-45-67 Formatted, but not hex
string.Format("{0:00-00-00-00}", string.Format("{0:X}", 1234567)); //Output: 01-23-45-67 Also dosn't work and is ugly.
string.Format("{0:X00-00-00-00}", 1234567); //Output: X01-23-45-67 Well. Still no success here.
```

Comment: First of all, an integer will not result in a MAC address as a MAC consists of 6 byte (48bit) and an int usually consists of 4 bytes (32bit). So you will not get a whole MAC address from an int. Other than that you could maybe use the solution in this answer with little adjustments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7310740/254797

Comment: Thanks, but I know that. The integer is only the device part of the MAC. The rest is determind by our manufacturer-id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will include a `-` delimiter;

```
BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(1234567))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(1234567))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a placeholder for each byte, and pass the integer in as an array:

```
// We have a format string that spits out hex for each byte seperated by a dash.
// ToString expects either a params or an object array, so let's get the bytes
// as a byte array, and convert it to an array of object
String.Format("{0:X}-{1:X}-{2:X}-{3:X}", BitConverter.GetBytes(1234567).Cast<Object>().ToArray())
```

Comment: Per Philipp, exchange the BitConverter.GetBytes() call with the byte array for your MAC addr. (add additional format string placeholders for the extra bytes) and this solution will still work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you turn it into a hex string, you could use this method to split it up into chunkSize 2, then rejoin it with hyphens

```
void Main()
{
    var str = string.Format("{0:X}", 12345678);
    var splits = Split(str, 2);
    var rejoinedSplits = string.Join("-",splits);
    Console.WriteLine (rejoinedSplits); //tested in linqpad, gave me BC-61-4E
}
static IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, int chunkSize)
{
      return Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / chunkSize).Select(i => str.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function to separate every 4 digits:

```
    public static string NumberToHexStr<T>(T obj) where T : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible // Any Number Type
    {
        string strHex = string.Format("0x{0:X2}", obj);
        if (strHex.Length > 6)
        {
            while (((strHex.Length - 2) % 4) != 0)
                strHex = strHex.Insert(2, "0");

            int nIndex = strHex.Length - 4;
            while (nIndex > 2)
            {
                strHex = strHex.Insert(nIndex, " ");
                nIndex -= 4;
            }
        }

        return strHex;
    }
```

Example: `1,407,392,063,619,074` will be displayed as `0x0005 0004 0003 0002`.